# Is there a way to save SQL table as a Python dataframe?

Tags: python, sql, bitbucket, databricks

I am trying to save the table on databricks (bitbucket is a source).

I can't figure out how to give a name to it the same way you do in Python (I do not have a lot of experience with Sql). For instance, if in python we: "df = pd.read_table("C:\Users...." and then we use it.

```
%sql
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE column3='apple';
```

I have this code, but I don't know how to continue to work with it using Python.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a connection

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

# Read sqlite query results into a pandas DataFrame
con = sqlite3.connect(r"c:\my\database.sqlite")
apple_df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE column3='apple'", con)
```